# Tricks for proving equalities under type cast

Tags: coq, dependent-type

I sometimes stumble across proofs that prove equalities in the form of

```
forall a b (p: a = b), C a = match p with | eq_refl => C b end
```

without resorting to applying `UIP_refl`, but the techniques used don't seem to "click" for me. Example 1:

```
Variable T: Type.

Inductive vector : nat -> Type :=
  | Vnil : vector 0
  | Vcons : forall n, T -> vector n -> vector (S n).

Fixpoint vappend n m (v1 : vector n) (v2 : vector m) : vector (n + m) :=
    match v1 with
    | Vnil => v2
    | Vcons x xs => Vcons x (vappend xs v2)
    end.

Lemma plus_assoc_trans : forall n m p : nat, n + (m + p) = n + m + p.
Proof.
induction n.
- reflexivity. 
- simpl. intros. f_equal. eapply IHn. 
Defined.

Theorem vappend_assoc : forall a b c (va : vector a) (vb : vector b) (vc : vector c),
      vappend (vappend va vb) vc
      = match plus_assoc_trans a b c in _ = X return vector X with
        | eq_refl => vappend va (vappend vb vc)
        end.
Proof.
    induction va.
    - simpl. reflexivity.                 (* A *)
    - simpl. intros. rewrite IHva.
      clear IHva.                         (* B *)
      destruct (plus_assoc_trans n b c).
      simpl. reflexivity.
Qed.
```

In line `A`, `reflexivity` does not work if I simply prove `plus_assoc_trans` through `lia`. Is this related to proof transparency? I understand line `B` - the clearing of induction hypothesis - to be necessary because otherwise we arrive at a proof state where two hypotheses have types where one prevents the other from being typable due to dependencies between terms. But is there a general rule or technique that describes this maneuver? Example 2:

```
Inductive ilist : nat -> Set :=
| Nil : ilist O
| Cons : forall n, A -> ilist n -> ilist (S n).

Fixpoint lenify (l: list A): ilist (length l) :=
  match l with
    | nil => Nil
    | x :: xs => Cons x (lenify xs)
  end.

Fixpoint delenify (n : nat) (l : ilist n): list A :=
  match l with
    | Nil => nil
    | Cons a t => a :: delenify t
  end.

Lemma delenify_len_eq: forall (n:nat) (l: ilist n), n = length (delenify l).
Proof.
induction l; simpl; auto.
Defined.

Goal forall (n:nat) (l: ilist n), lenify (delenify l) = 
      match delenify_len_eq l with 
         eq_refl => l
      end.
Proof.
induction l.
- reflexivity.
- simpl.
  rewrite IHl.
  rewrite <- delenify_len_eq.
  simpl.
  reflexivity.
Defined.
```

Here simple rewrites and application of induction hypothesis works, but that's not always possible due to the resulting term being "ill-typed". Are there some decent resources on constructing proofs involving dependent types and casting?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why reflexivity works in `A` is due to the way `plus_assoc_trans` was defined. To see this, you can do

```
intros.
set (e := plus_assoc_trans _ _ _).
cbn in e.
```

at `A`, and you'll see that `e` reduces to `eq_refl`, which lets the pattern-maching compute further. If the proof was defined in a different way (for instance using `lia`), or made opaque (closing it with `Qed` rather than defined), forbidding Coq to reduce it, then this reduction would not happen.

As for `B`, and more generally the question of dealing with definitions and proof that involve dependently-typed terms, although there are quite a few useful technique (as you noticed, clearing hypothesis to avoid ill-typed terms is one), there is quite a bit of skill involved…

A good resource to learn some of these techniques is probably Chlipala's [Certified Programming with Dependent Types](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/).